# React Hook "useAxios" is called in function I want to use useAxios in button click event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am developing using react and antd.

This is useAxios I wrote.

code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';

const useAxios = ({ url, method, body = null, headers = null }) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = () => {
    axios[method](url, headers, body)
      .then((res) => {
        setResponse(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setloading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [method, url, body, headers]);

  return { response, error, loading };
};

export default useAxios;
```

This is the login component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import useAxios from '../hooks/useAxios';

const LoginForm = () => {
  const axios = useAxios;

  const onFinish = (body) => {
    const test = axios({
      url: 'api/auth/login',
      method: 'post',
      body,
    });
    console.log(test);
  };

  const findIDAndPassword = () => {
    console.log('findIDAndPassword');
  };

  return (
    <Form name="basic" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.Item
        name="id"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your id!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input placeholder="ID" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password placeholder="PASSWORD" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" block>
          login
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
      <Button type="link" block onClick={findIDAndPassword}>
        findIDAndPassword
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

but it gives me this error how to fix?

src\components\LoginForm.js Line 7:18: React Hook "useAxios" is called in function "onFinish" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use" react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/og592.png

Comment: You saved a reference to the hook `const axios = useAxios;` and then invoked it in the `onFinish` callback. The `useAxios` hook doesn't return a function so it's a bit unclear what you want the behavior to be here.

Comment: rather use this library https://github.com/simoneb/axios-hooks

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can't post like that, first thing is, you can't use your hook inside a function. So what you can do is:

1. Create a hook, and return `{loading, response, error, operation}` from your hook.
2. And call that operation from your method.

Here is the working example of yours, you can continue from here:

```js
// useAxios.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

export const useAxios = () => {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(undefined);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const operation = async(params) => {
        try {
            setLoading(true)
            const result = await axios.request(params);
            setResponse(result.data);
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return { response, error, loading, operation };
};

export default useAxios;
```

In here, you can see, I've return another method named operation, which is used to do fetch the data, or call some API. *[Note: I've slightly changes your code to es6 for better understanding]*

And here is another file where I've been using this hook:

```js
// app.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import useAxios from "./useAxios";

const App = () => {
    const { response, loading, error, operation } = useAxios();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const submit = (data) => {
        operation({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/posts',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
            data
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (response !== null) {
            setData(response);
        }
    }, [response]);

    return (
        <>
            {loading && <span>Loading...</span>}
            {data && <span>{data.name}</span>}
            <br />
            <button onClick={(e) => submit({ name: 'random name' })}>Click me</button>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Now in here, you can call this method and pass all the axiosParams and then `useAxios` hooks works as you expected.

And if you wants to fetch the data (or `GET` api), you can call operation method inside your `useEffect` hook.

Comment: If I want to make a GET api call, and I call the operation method inside useEffect I get an error. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component